# Template class names in weird forms (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm retrieving the names of all the classes in the current runtime in .NET, for the purpose of identifying object and function declarations in sourcecode that's given as input to my program, but templates seem a bit off, for example I've got this among the output:

```
hashset`1+elementcount[t]
hashset`1+slot[t]
hashset`1+enumerator[t]
```

which I obtain more or less from this simple code (there's some similar code that gets the referenced assemblies but essentially does the following for each of those instead of the executing assembly).

```
foreach (Type t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
            {
                types.Add(t.ToString().Split('.').Last().ToLower());
            }
```

For now I can of course just `Split()` the strings to get the first part, before the ` mark, but I was wondering if anyone knows exactly what this might be. The three lines above are consecutive, and a couple more entries for HashSet in my results also have this 1+something thing, so I'm positive it's the actual HashSet class. (note: I'm turning everything to lowercase currently but disabling it doesn't seem to change anything.)

So... anyone know what's this notation? Not sure how to google it, but copy-pasting some lines to Google and enclosing in quotes returns either no results or very random threads that don't end up having the line in them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI: .NET does not have templates, but generic types (generics). They are not the same, despite both using the angular brackets `Name<T>` style.

Comment: Those look like generic type arity markings.  See [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20481/NET-Type-Internals-From-a-Microsoft-CLR-Perspecti), at the bottom of the page, and [here](https://alexandrnikitin.github.io/blog/dotnet-generics-under-the-hood/), about halfway down the page.

Comment: @elgonzo thanks for the tip, I'll look into the template vs. generic thing, everyday something new... And I'm positively embarrassed that I didn't think of `t.Name`, that's what you get for writing code after midnight :P

Comment: @RobertHarvey looks like that's the thing, might wanna throw in a couple of extra lines of explanation (for the sake of completion) and make it an answer so I can mark it as answered?

Comment: @user3079666, i made a mistake in my 2nd comment, being led astray by your code. `t.Name` will only provide you the type name excluding the generic type parameters. But which you seem to be interested in. Hence, i deleted my comment

Comment: Well, I don't know exactly why Microsoft does it this way, and those particular names look unfamiliar to me.  I do know that Microsoft likes to munge names in the IL in ways that are illegal in C#, so that it's impossible for you to write an identifier that will clash with one of their internal ones.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, i think it is unrelated to C# itself, as the formatting of the type name returned by the Type object is probably unrelated to and not concerned by the language some source code was written in (C#, VB.NET, F#...).

Comment: @elgonzo: I can't speak for the other languages as I don't actually know their syntax rules in depth.  But I do know C#.

Comment: @elgonzo actually generic type parameters are not that necessary for my original intentions, I just happened upon them and got curious, I probably could indeed have used `t.Name`

Comment: @RobertHarvey, i tried to say that what Type.FullName/Type.ToString() returns is not due to some conflict between some source language grammar and the CLR. What i tried to say is that i do not think that there is some connection between some aspect of C# and the result returned by Type.FullName/Type.ToString() that demands this formatting as you seem to believe.

Comment: @elgonzo: I never made that claim anyway.  Stop trying to language-lawyer my comments, please.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, you did implicitly: "_so that it's impossible for you to write an identifier that will clash with one of their internal ones._" You could not possibly make that statement without having source code language like C# in consideration. Anyway, i will stop now ;-)

Comment: @elgonzo: Well, that fact is not in dispute.  Microsoft does, in fact, munge their local names in the IL to prevent clashes with user-written source code.  Might not have any relevance here, but there it is.

Comment: Think of types like `Action`, `Action<T>`, `Action<T,U>` ... they all need distinguishable names in IL. So the c# compiler adds the arity to the common 'Action'-name to hide the fact that all these types are completly independant despite of the 'same' name.